# Tax forms to report Capital Gain/Losses for Non-Resident Alien on F-1 visa?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, f1-student-visa, form-1099-div, 1099-b

I am a non-resident alien on F-1 Visa. I recieved a W-2 from my employer. I have also sold stocks and etfs through robo-advisors. I have recieved forms 1099-B and 1099-DIV from them. Where should I report these stock trades? On Schedule D or Schedule NEC of 1040NR?

Answer (score 1):

The answer that @ksernow provided is incorrect. You can consult the official IRS answer [here](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/the-taxation-of-capital-gains-of-nonresident-alien-students-scholars-and-employees-of-foreign-governments).

In the Conclusions section you will find:

> Nonresident alien students and scholars and alien employees of foreign governments and international organizations who, at the time of their arrival in the United States, intend to reside in the United States for longer than 1 year are subject to the 30 percent taxation on their capital gains during any tax year (usually calendar year) in which they are present in the United States for 183 days or more, unless a tax treaty provides for a lesser rate of taxation.
>
> This assumes that such capital gains are not effectively connected
>   with the conduct of a United States trade or business.
>
> **These capital gains would be reported on page 4 (not page 1) of Form
>   1040NR and would not be reported on a Schedule D because they are
>   being taxed at a flat rate of 30 percent or at a reduced flat rate
>   under a tax treaty.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to report them on Schedule D. Since you are on F1 visa, you can try 1040nra.com they allow to you enter capital gains